# How can I delete all scripts and triggers, and remove unauthorised access from my account?

Tags: security, google-apps-script, triggers, permissions, unauthorized

I opened a virus file and someone got access to my emails. After this, I have changed the password and enabled 2FA, but the hacker is manipulating my Google Script.

I keep receiving emails, for example:

> Your script, Untitled project, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your settings for receiving future failure notifications, click here.

I don't understand what is happening; how can I delete all of these scripts and triggers, and ultimately remove this person's access from my account?

Comment: About `i keep recieving emails like : Your script, Untitled project, has recently failed to finish successfully.`, I cannot recommend accessing to "click here". Because I'm not sure whether the email is the correct email. So, in this case, for example, when you check your all triggers at https://script.google.com/home , can you see that trigger? If you can see the trigger, you can remove the trigger. And also, you can see and delete the Google Apps Script. But, I'm not sure about your detailed situation. So if this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: In addition to what Tanaike said, checkout third party access [here](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions)

Answer (score 1):

To completely remove all Google apps scripts access from your compromised account,

1. Change your Google account password
2. Visit [apps script dashboard](https://script.google.com/home) and remove [all triggers](https://script.google.com/home/triggers) and [all scripts](https://script.google.com/home) there.
3. Visit [your Google account third party apps page](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) and remove all apps with permissions there.

Make sure you're logged into the correct google account.